# how can i use router object inside firebase function?

Tags: angular2-routing, angularfire2

If anyone could help me with this, it would be much appreciated.  I am unable to use router inside `firebase` function.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-listings',
   templateUrl: './listings.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./listings.component.css']
})

export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
  listings: any;
  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    public router: Router
  ) {
```

This is the `firebase` function where I'm unable to use router.

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('loggedIn');
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('not loggedIn');
```

Console appears to be working fine, too.

```
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => {
      this.listings = listings;
      console.log(listings);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using the Firebase SDK instead of AngularFire's [authentication](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the arrow function to access the `this` keyword.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('loggedIn');
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('not loggedIn');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
});
```

With AngularFire's authentication...

```js
constructor(
    private af: AngularFire,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    public router: Router
) {
    this.af.auth.take(1).subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log('loggedIn');
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            console.log('not loggedIn');
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Btw take is not a property of AngularFireAuth. It's working fine without it

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';` [take](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html) will manage the subscription for you. Without it your subscription will persist. You must either manually unsubscribe, use the async pipe, or one of the operators like `take`.